# cloudcompare mount hard drive issue

Tags: linux, python-3.x, point-clouds

I tried to mount other hard drive in CloudCompare, and tried the link and the command already, but still didn't work. 
Could someone tell me how to fix it? thx

https://www.danielgm.net/cc/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2376

```
sudo snap connect  cloudcompare:removable-media  :removable-media
```

Comment: Which version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CloudCompare v2.10.1, and the code works for me.

```
sudo snap refresh -- stable
snap install cloudcompare
sudo snap refresh
sudo snap connect  cloudcompare:removable-media  :removable-media
```